# Android Storage Access Framework Document Create File & Dir Recursively

Tags: android, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

First of all.

Thank you for reading this question.

Currently, I am new to Android(Like it has been a month I've started learning)

And now I need to write Files and Directories "RECURSIVELY" on SD card.

My code below kind of works.....

```
private void recursiveFolderDownload(String src, Uri dst) throws SftpException {
    Log.e("dst",dst.toString());
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, dst);
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileAndFolderList = channelSftp.ls(src);
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry item : fileAndFolderList) {
        if (!item.getAttrs().isDir()) {
            DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("",item.getFilename());
            write(src + "/" + item.getFilename(),newFile.getUri());
        } else if (!(".".equals(item.getFilename()) || "..".equals(item.getFilename()))) {
            DocumentFile newDir = pickedDir.createDirectory(item.getFilename());
            recursiveFolderDownload(src + "/" + item.getFilename(), newDir.getUri());
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly speaking, every and each files&dirs I write are just written only on the same path

which is the top(content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/E3AB-1A0D%3A)

I mean it!

Every files and directories are just written on top!

Am I missing something here?

If I do, please wise man guide me with a solution.

And again, Thank you for reading this question

hope u have a nice day

Comment: Try using `DocumentFile` as the second parameter to your `recursiveFolderDownload()` function, rather than unwrapping the `DocumentFile` via `newDir.getUri()` then trying to recreate the `DocumentFile` via `fromTreeUri()`.

Comment: @CommonWare I am sorry but could you write that as a code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works better:

```
private void recursiveFolderDownload(String src, DocumentFile pickedDir) throws SftpException {
    Log.e("dst",dst.toString());

    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileAndFolderList = channelSftp.ls(src);

    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry item : fileAndFolderList) {
        if (!item.getAttrs().isDir()) {
            DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("",item.getFilename());
            write(src + "/" + item.getFilename(),newFile.getUri());
        } else if (!(".".equals(item.getFilename()) || "..".equals(item.getFilename()))) {
            DocumentFile newDir = pickedDir.createDirectory(item.getFilename());
            recursiveFolderDownload(src + "/" + item.getFilename(), newDir);
        }
    }
}
```

In your existing code, you:

- Create a directory using `createDirectory()`
- Unwrap the `DocumentFile` from `createDirectory()` using `getUri()`
- Try to recreate the `DocumentFile` using `fromTreeUri()`

It is safer, and more efficient, to just keep using `DocumentFile` until you absolutely need a `Uri` (in `write()`).

Your initial call to `recursiveFolderDownload()` would use the `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, dst)` call that I removed from your original sample.

Comment: @KigaelLee: The problem is that `getUri()` and `fromTreeUri()` are not opposite operations. See [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148020926) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for useful information. May the God Bless You